# Maximum size of an "open convex polygon" made by intersection of lines?

Tags: discrete-geometry

Suppose we have $n$ lines in the plane. What is the maximum size of an "open convex polygon" that we can get from the intersection of lines?

For example, in the following picture, we can see an "open" triangle coming from the intersection of three lines.

Any hint would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "general position"? Whatever it is, that should be edited into your question.

Comment: @quasi: I'm sorry, it means there are no parallel lines.

Comment: Actually, I do not that condition. So I will delete it.

Comment: Also, in your example image, I don't see a triangle.

Comment: The middle region is an open triangle, 3 sided!

Comment: If it is "lines" and no segments then the area should be $\infty$. If it is finite segments of the same length then the regular polygon would do the job. You mean something else?

Comment: @dmtri: I mean line (unbounded). and yes the area is $\infinity.$ I wanted to know how many sides an open convex polygon could have?